# Setting minimum length of password in web2py

Tags: web2py

I am using auth module for login in my web2py application. I want to have minimum length of my password as 8. Where do I make the changes for this to take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `auth.define_tables()`, set the minimum password length as follows:

```
auth.settings.password_min_length = 8
```

Alternatively, you could add the `IS_STRONG` validator to the password field, or replace its default `CRYPT` validator with a version specifying `min_length=8`.